# Returned Rowversion data from a POST is not valid base64

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, base64

I am sending Rowversion data to my view in order to test for Concurrency issue for Update/Delete of a record to SQL Server. The Rowversion data in the record is Byte[] which has to be converted to a Base64 string so it can be serialized. This is being done by a getter in my ViewModel. The returned Base64 data is being converted back to Byte[] by a setter. (I believe this is standard practice when dealing with SQL Server rowversion data.)

My ViewModel is...

```
    public byte[] RowVersionId { get; set; }
    public string RowVersionIdBase64
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.RowVersionId != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(this.RowVersionId);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                this.RowVersionId = null;
            }
            else
            {
                this.RowVersionId = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
            }

        }
    }
```

The Post causes error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

The Post Parameters as displayed by Firebug are...(just relevant data shown here - sorry but SO mangles the layout somewhat)

...
RowVersionIdBase64
AAAAAAAAF3E=
RowVersionId[]
0
RowVersionId[]
0
RowVersionId[]
0
RowVersionId[]
0
RowVersionId[]
0
RowVersionId[]
0
RowVersionId[]
23
RowVersionId[]
113
...

The Post Source is...(full post data shown here)

PropertyId=1&RateFromDate=Sat+Apr+15+2017+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B1000+(AUS+Eastern+Standard+Time)&RateToDate
=Sat+Apr+15+2017+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B1000+(AUS+Eastern+Standard+Time)&RateName=fff&RateComment=&MinimumStay
=1&WeekRate=0&WeekendRate=&WeekEndNightRate=150&MidweekNightRate=100&MonthRate=0&FullPeriodRate=0&Cancelled
=false&DateCreated=Thu+Apr+14+2016+07%3A57%3A16+GMT%2B1000+(AUS+Eastern+Standard+Time)&DateCancelled
=&RowVersionId%5B%5D=0&RowVersionId%5B%5D=0&RowVersionId%5B%5D=0&RowVersionId%5B%5D=0&RowVersionId%5B
%5D=0&RowVersionId%5B%5D=0&RowVersionId%5B%5D=23&RowVersionId%5B%5D=113&RowVersionIdBase64=AAAAAAAAF3E%3D&Id=7

What is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: I commented out the setter in my ViewModel as I was sure the error was occurring there but the same error still occurs. So where should I look?

Comment: It looks like RowVersionId in my ViewModel is the issue. I commented it out (and the whole of RowVersionIdBase64 also - as opposed to just commenting out the setter as per above) and the error went away.

Comment: Did you find the reason and a solution?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this error is if 2 html inputs have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
--rowvers is define as a timestamp in the table

  SELECT TOP (100) 
rowvers ,
 ( SELECT CAST(rowvers as varbinary(max)) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64 )
  FROM
    [hpodb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

cast one more time to not break SSMS export

```sql
SELECT TOP (100) 
rowvers ,
 cast(( SELECT CAST(rowvers as varbinary(max)) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64 ) as varchar)
  FROM [hpodb].[dbo].[mytable]
```